# Regular Expressions to accept strings where every two successive 0s are followed by a 1

Tags: regular-expressions

How do I define a Regular Expression for the language L = {w|every two successive 0s are followed by a 1} ?

I don't have any idea on how to even approach this problem, primarily because it says "**every two 0s**".

Comment: If you struggle with those kind of exercises, you can always consider a detour via an other representation of the language (e.g. NFAs) and then transform it via the common techniques to your desired representation. However, in this case, I think the regex is quite straight forward (as is the NFA):
"As long as you only read 1s everything is fine, when you read a 0 then you can only have 1 or 01 as following substring. You can repeat this arbitrary often."
Is this a helpful hint?

Comment: It sure is,  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take either 1, or 01, or 001 and repeat any number of times. Plus there can be a single 0 at the end.